# workflow sharepoint plugin to use

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, moss, sharepoint-2007

i need to know few things please

1- is sharepoint with windows workflow foundation (a good and dependable engine)

2- i am using .NET and sharepoint, what would be the best workflow plugin for sharepoint

we need it provide easy interface to create the work flow, connect and affect oracle, SQLSERVER, work with moss2007, give us full control on the look and design of the form page as well as the approval or any pages and forms used within the workflow ( am i asking for too much !!:) )

the workflows will be used for approvals, change requests, requests of equipments, leave application, .... etc

Comment: kindly elaborate your requirement for plugin

Comment: we need it provide easy interface to create the work flow, connect and affect oracle, SQLSERVER, work with moss2007, give us full control on the look and design of the form page as well as the approval or any pages and forms used within the workflow ( am i asking for too much !!:) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows Workflow Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation) is very strong and can be relied upon for SharePoint workflows.
In the market there are lot of plugins available for workflow creation.

1. SharePoint Desginer
2. [ShareVis Designer](http://www.sharevis.com/products/productsDesigner.php)
3. [Nintex Workflow](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/Workflow2007.aspx)
4. [Captaris Workflow](http://www.captaris.com/workflow/captaris_workflow_sharepoint_wizard/index.html)

I have provided a few references above. Kindly evaluate your needs and use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint makes use of Windows Workflow Foundation and it's a pretty stable and powerful solution. If you need an easy to use interface to create workflows, you may want to take a look at Nintex Workflow. We use it at the company and are very pleased with it. There are versions for both SharePoint 2007 and 2010.

http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Pages/default.aspx